# How to use in_array function corretly?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, each

Hi guys I cannot undersetand why the in_array function is not check if any array element is empty. I want it to check if any value is empty it should return true. I have set all values to empty '' and still it is returning no instead of yes. Any help appreciated. thanks

```
print_r($vals);

foreach($vals as $value) {
    if(in_array("",$value, true)) echo 'yes'; else echo 'no';
}
```

Returns:-

Array ( [0] => '' [1] => '' [2] => '' [3] => '' ) nononono

Comment: can you please give an example of what $vals array should look like?

Comment: `$value` is just an empty string in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you will not need foreach, just use like this

```
if(in_array(" ",$vals, true)) 
    echo 'yes'; 
else 
    echo 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to check empty string why not use:

```
foreach($vals as $value) {
    if($value == "") echo 'yes'; else echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in_array is used to check whether a particular value is present in an array
Kindly refer  https://www.php.net/in_array
Your problems solution can be sought through
foreach and  if  loops as mentioned in other answers